# Angular - How to style my form to accomodate all the field data

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on an application using Angular-7 frontend. In the form that is shown below, the form field elements are truncated and not everything is displayed:

[image: form image]

**addModal**

```
<div id="addModal" class="modal" style="background-color: rgb(0,0,0); background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Add New Role</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" (click)='closeAddModal()'>
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="!error.name">
                    {{ error.name }}
                  </div>
            <form #editRoleForm=ngForm>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="name" name="name" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="form.name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Permissions</label>
                    <div *ngFor="let permission of permissions">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ permission.name }}" value="{{ permission.name }}" (change)="checkboxAdd($event)"> {{ permission.name }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)='addModalSubmit()' [disabled]="!editRoleForm.valid">Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)='closeAddModal()'>Close</button>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

**editModal**

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal" style="background-color: rgb(0,0,0); background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Role</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" (click)='closeEditModal()'>
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="!error.name">
                    {{ error.name }}
                  </div>
            <form #newRoleForm=ngForm>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name"  required [(ngModel)]="data.name"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Permissions</label>
                  <div *ngFor="let permission of permissions">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="{{ permission.name }}" value="{{ permission.name }}" (change)="checkbox($event)" *ngIf="!data.permission.includes(permission.name)">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ permission.name }}" value="{{ permission.name }}" (change)="checkbox($event)" *ngIf="data.permission.includes(permission.name)" checked> {{ permission.name }}
                  </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  [disabled]="!newRoleForm.valid" (click)='editsubmit()'>Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)='closeEditModal()'>Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

How do I style the form, so that all the form elements will be displayed (I can't even see the submit button)? It may even be in three columns.

Comment: I'm not sure what libraries you are using for the modal and such, but I know the NgbModal with bootstrap will scroll if you enable it in the options.

Comment: For a large select list, you could do a multiselect instead, or you could display the items next to each other. To display them next to each other, you have to make sure they're inline, or that you're using some sort of grid system

Comment: @Chad K - How do I do this? Can you show me a sample?  Also, how do I make the checkbox to be in 3 columns?

Comment: For the grid system, use something like bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Comment: For the multiselect, it might be easiest to use a library. I searched 'Angular Multiselect' on google and found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown